# Как узнать разницу в днях между двумя днями?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нужно узнать сколько дней между днями например Пятницей (константное число 6,`Calendar.FRIDAY`) и Понедельником (константное число 2, `Calendar.MONDAY`).

Я пишу повторяющийся будильник под андроид, в базе лежат числа по каким дням нужно проигрывать будильник, допустим 246 (Пн,Ср,Пт). Если сегодня пятница нам нужно завести будильник на Пн, следовательно разница в днях - 3 дня. Как это узнать программно?

Comment: 6-2 не работает? =)

Comment: А с понедельника по следующий понедельник у вас 7 дней или 0? А так вообще вычтите числовые значения, если получилось отрицательное, прибавьте 7.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev 
а если сегодня пятница?=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(День2 - День1 )` если это меньще 0, тогда + 7

```
((День2 - День1) + 7) (mod 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Выбери из этих вариантов нужный:

```
(a - b + 7) % 7
(a - b + 6) % 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTimeS = new DateTime(2017, 4, 3, 0, 0);
DateTime dateTimeE = new DateTime(2017, 4, 11, 0, 0);

Period period = new Period(dateTimeS, dateTimeE);

System.out.println( period.getDays()+
                ":"+period.getMonths()+
                ":"+period.getYears());
```

Comment: Зачем здесь код из вашего вопроса?